# Reading data from array and write to append to existing file:My code is not appending data as expected

Tags: c#, filestream

My application reads data from an array and then writes to an existing file. It shall write to the end of the line, but when I run the application it does not append anything.

After researching I came across [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946421/append-data-to-existing-file-in-c-sharp). I modified my code as answered on that post, I now receive an error:

> 'FileStream' is a `namespace` but is used like a `type`.

I Added the `System.IO` namespace but still the problem persists.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file_path = @"C:\Users\myfolder\Desktop\FileStream\Processed\Output.txt";
        string data = " ";


        try
        {
            using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter author = new StreamWriter(aFile, true))
            {
                string[] output_receiptNos = ReadFile().ToArray();
                for (int index = 0; index < output_receiptNos.Length; index++)
                {
                    data = output_receiptNos[index];
                    author.WriteLine(data);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Data Sucessfully Processed");

            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not process Data");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have defined a namespace `FileStream` in your project?

Comment: Something is wrong in your code. There is no constructor overload for the StreamWriter object that takes a Stream and a boolean. How do you compile this code?

Comment: I receive the error indicated in my post when i compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileStream` adds nothing to the work of the `StreamWriter` with its [predefined constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) that takes a string (for filename) and a boolean (for appending(overwrite data). And as written is not compilable because the `StreamWriter` has no constructors that takes a Stream and a Boolean.

As someone has already mentioned in the comments, you probably have a conflict in your code with some namespace oddly named "FileStream".  (A bad idea by the way).
However, I think you could remove the error using directly the StreamWriter class.
Then take your time to find why the compiler thinks that you have a namespace named "FileStream"

```
        using (StreamWriter author = new StreamWriter(file_path, true))
        {
            string[] output_receiptNos = ReadFile().ToArray();
            for (int index = 0; index < output_receiptNos.Length; index++)
            {
                data = output_receiptNos[index];
                author.WriteLine(data);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Data Sucessfully Processed");
        }
```

Comment: my first approach was to using the StreamWriter class directly. It displays the message Data successfully processed.Meaning that section the code was executed but the when i check the destination file i only find the old data

Comment: It should not be necessary, but try adding a `author.Flush();` before exiting from the using statement (of course you are absolutely sure that `ReadFile` returns something inside the `output_receiptNos` array right?)

Comment: Yes. am have tested that and display the count of output_receiptNos in a messagebox.