# File doesn't update when writing to it using System.IO.Stream C#

Tags: c#, .net, stream, runtime-error, filestream

I  am using the following code to write the length `byte[] val` to the end of a file and then write `byte[] val` itself

```
byte[] len = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16) val.Length);
int fileLen = (int)new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
{
    stream.Write(len, fileLen, 2);
    stream.Write(val, fileLen + 2, val.Length);
}
```

And I get this Error on the last line of the `using` block:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

When I check the file I see that the stream didn't write the first 2 bytes at all, and this is the reason that the error occurs. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that you're providing an offset where you shouldn't, as the exception message states.

For any file length greater than zero, the first `Write()` will already throw, as the offset plus length will lie outside the `len`'s bounds.

The offset parameter denotes the offset in the byte array, which in both cases should be zero, as you want to write the entire array:

```
stream.Write(len, 0, len.Length);
stream.Write(val, 0, val.Length);
```

If instead you want to append to the end of a file, see [Append data to existing file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946421/append-data-to-existing-file-in-c-sharp). If you want to start writing anywhere else, use `Seek()` to change the stream's position.

Comment: ohhh, I thought that it meant the offset in the file, how do I change the offset in the file then?

Comment: See the updated answer. Either use `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)` or `Seek()` to the wanted position.

Comment: Yeah, the `Seek()` is what I was looking for, thank you!